# android cut string from specefic char till char

Tags: java, android, string

I have a simple question about cutting the string in android developing.

Imagine i have a string something like **:**

```
#badword!next@Word%bad2
              <-->
```

And i want to cut it to have this **:**

```
Word
```

I mean, Cut str from begin till this char `@` and after that get everything till you see `%` char.

How can i do that with android functions?

Thanks.

Comment: @HiteshJain tnx, i am trying.

Answer (score 0):

Using string operations

1)Int a =  get first index of "@"
2) int b = get index of "%"
3)use substring with a & b

Methods are

public int indexOf (int c)
Returns the first index of the given code point, or -1. The search starts at the beginning and moves towards the end of this string.

public int indexOf (int c, int start)
Returns the next index of the given code point, or -1. The search starts at the given offset and moves towards the end of this string.

public String substring (int start, int end)
Returns a string containing the given subsequence of this string. The returned string shares this string's backing array.

Parameters
start   the start offset.
end the end+1 offset.